# Problema em DialogResult tendo que apertar o botão 3 vezes para abrir

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tendo um problema sério de recorrência com o DialogResult.

[image: Tela de Login]

Essa é a tela de Login,graças ao uso do DialogResult,existe um erro estranho,você tem de apertar o Logar duas vezes. A primeira ele pega que o DialogResult é OK mas para ali,ele não retorna e testa,você tem que clicar uma segunda vez para ele prosseguir.

Eis o código do botão:

```
private void btnLogar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);

        ModeloLogin.Login = txtLogin.Text;
        ModeloLogin.Senha = txtSenha.Text;

        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(cx.StringConexao);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select login, senha FROM registro WHERE login = '" + ModeloLogin.Login + "'AND senha = '" + ModeloLogin.Senha + "'",conexao);
        conexao.Open();

        bool Verifica = cmd.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
        if (Verifica == true)
        {
            btnLogar.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            count = count + 1;
            if (count > 1) 
            {
            conexao.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Login efetuado com sucesso! Bem-vindo.", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
            this.IsNewLogged = true;
            conexao.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select nome from registro where login = '"+ ModeloLogin.Login + "'",conexao);
            ModeloLogin.Nome = Convert.ToString(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
            conexao.Close();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select permissao from registro where login = '" + ModeloLogin.Login + "'",conexao);
            conexao.Open();
            ModeloLogin.Permissao = Convert.ToString(cmd3.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login ou senha incorretos! Tente novamente.", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        conexao.Close();
    }
```

E aqui está o código do Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        frmLogin f = new frmLogin();
        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            frmDecisao d = new frmDecisao();
            if(d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
            Application.Run(new frmPrincipal());
            f.Dispose();
            d.Dispose();
                }
            if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
            {
                Application.Run(new frmPrincipal2());
                f.Dispose();
                d.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Originalmente era para ele fazer que o click do Logar é um DialogResult OK e retornar para o Program.cs e testa ele na condição,entretanto a primeira vez que ele é clicado ele para no DialogResult OK e na segunda ele continua e retorna ao program.cs alguém sabe me dizer o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No primeiro clique voce esta definindo o dialogresult do botão, no segundo clique, o botão retorna o valor.

Utilize this.dialogresult = .... Pra definir direto no retorno do form

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo auxílio,realmente funcionou do jeito que precisava.